# Is there a way of reading the last element of an array with bash?

Tags: bash, array

If I have an array with 5 elements, for example:

`[a][b][c][d][e]`

Using echo `${myarray[4]}` I can see what it holds.

But what if I didn't know the number of elements in a given array? Is there a way of reading the last element of an unknown length array? i.e. The first element reading from the right to the left for any array?

I would like to know how to do this in bash.

Comment: `$@` isn't exactly an array (can't be subscripted). For it, see [Getting the last argument passed to a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1853946/5353461).

Answer (score 169, accepted):

[As of bash 4.2](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/36f2c40/CHANGES#L3034-L3035), you can just [use a negative index](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays) `${myarray[-1]}` to get the last element. You can do the same thing for the second-last, and so on; in Bash:

> If the subscript used to reference an element of an indexed array
> evaluates to a number less than zero, it is interpreted as relative to
> one greater than the maximum index of the array, so negative indices
> count back from the end of the array, and an index of -1 refers to the
> last element.

The same also works for assignment. When it says "expression" it really means an expression; you can write in any arithmetic expression there to compute the index, including one that computes using the length of the array `${#myarray[@]}` explicitly like `${myarray[${#myarray[@]} - 1]}` for earlier versions.

Comment: You can do that in `ksh` and `zsh` as well.

Comment: With `zsh` though, by default arrays are 1-indexed, unlike `bash` and `ksh` where they are 0-indexed.

Comment: @StephenKitt; The `${a[-1]}` works in all the three mentioned shells, though. (Only the bulky "calculated" method needs (in `zsh`) `${a[${#a[@]}]}` as opposed to `bash` and `ksh` where you'd have to use `${a[${#a[@]}-1]}`.)

Comment: Yes, of course; the short answer to this question doesn't change, but since the long form was mentioned I thought it necessary to point out the difference in behaviour there.

Comment: @StephenKitt; Yes, the long version had been added later to the answer. Just want to make sure.

Comment: Negative index only work in bash 4.3 and above.

Comment: The version of Bash included with Mac OS X as of at least v10.11.5 is only 3.2, so this doesn't work on Macs.

Comment: But getting tail is not so simple: `${a[@]:0:${#a[@]} - 1}`.

Comment: Also, for `$@` in a function starting index is `1` (`${@:1}`) unless you want to include the program name. In which case do note that `${#@}` doesn't take it into account. And negative indices doesn't work for `$@`: `${@[-1]}`.

Comment: Note that for `$@` a different syntax is required: `${@:(-1)}`.

Comment: Apparently [-1] syntax is version specific, it didn't work for me either. But this worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/16109755/10694438

Answer (score 67):

#### Modern bash (v4.1 or better)

You can read the last element at index `-1`:

```
$ a=(a b c d e f)
$ echo ${a[-1]}
f
```

Support for accessing numerically-indexed arrays from the end using negative indexes [started with bash version 4.1-alpha](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges).

#### Older bash (v4.0 or earlier)

You must get the array length from `${#a[@]}` and then subtract one to get the last element:

```
$ echo ${a[${#a[@]}-1]}
f
```

Since bash treats array subscripts as an arithmetic expression, there is no need for additional notation, such as `$((...))`, to force arithmetic evaluation.

Comment: the last one doesn't work for me; I'm using Bash v4.1.2(1): instead of printing the last item, it just prints out the whole array.

Comment: @cuonglm's answer works, however.

Comment: The answer would be even better if you could qualify `modern` with a version.

Comment: @Samveen The negative index feature was added in bash version 4.1-alpha.  (Alnswer updated).

Comment: Exactly what was needed to make the anwser perfect.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was using echo ${a[$((${#a[@]}-1]))} because I didn't know about "bash treats array subscripts as an arithmetic expression".

Answer (score 25):

`bash` array assignment, reference, unsetting with negative index were only [added in bash 4.3](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS). With older version of `bash`, you can use expression in index `array[${#array[@]-1}]`

Another way, also work with older version of `bash` (bash 3.0 or better):

```
$ a=('[a]' '[b]' '[c]' '[d]' '[e]')
$ printf %s\\n "${a[@]:(-1)}"
[e]
```

or:

```
$ printf %s\\n "${a[@]: -1}"
[e]
```

Using negative offset, you need to separate `:` with `-` to avoid being confused with the `:-` expansion.

Comment: Make that `"${a[@]: -1}"` and it will work (besides `bash` and `zsh`) also in `ksh`.

Comment: The Kornshell docs (http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html) specify it completely. (Haven't inspected the docs of `zsh` or `bash`; but I tested it in all three shells.)

Comment: @Janis: re-read bash documentation, it also mentioned about this one, too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

## array

The oldest alternative(s) in bash (Since bash 3.0+) are:

```
$ a=(aa bb cc dd ee)
$ echo "${a[@]:(-1)}   ${a[@]: -1}   ${a[@]:(~0)}   ${a[@]:~0}"
ee   ee   ee   ee
```

The space is required to avoid the interpretation of `:` followed by a minus `-` as the expansion of `"${var:-abc}"` (Use Default Values).

The `~` is an arithmetic **[bitwise negation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/791328/9110606)** (equivalent to one's complement or *flip all bits*). From man bash:

> ARITHMETIC EVALUATION
>
> ```
>       ! ~         logical and bitwise negation
> ```

Since bash-4.2+ also:

```
$ echo "${a[-1]}   ${a[(~0)]}"
ee   ee
```

Since bash 5.0+ also:

```
$ echo "${a[~0]}"
ee
```

For all bash versions (older bash):

```
$ echo "${a[   ${#a[@]}-1   ]}"    # spaces added **only** for readability
ee
```

## @

For positional arguments (since bash 2.01):

```
$ set aa bb cc dd ee
$ echo "${@:(-1)} ${@:~0} ${@: -1} ${@:$#}   ${!#}"
ee ee ee   ee
```

A portable solution for all shells is to use eval:

```
eval printf '"%s\n"' \"\${$#}\"
```

Answer (score -1):

Also you can do this:

```
$ a=(a b c d e f)
$ echo ${a[$(expr ${#a[@]} - 1)]}
```

Result:

```
$ f
```

What you're doing is getting all the count of elements in the array and subtract -1 due you're getting all the elements, not starting from the array index that is 0.